# Simulate Missing Data (i.e. Mask Data) in R to Test Imputation Accuracy

Tags: r, masking, simulate, missing-data, cross-validation

I want to determine a program's imputation accuracy using SNP genotype data, so I need to mask a portion of the SNP calls to simulate missing data.

I've been testing my code on this subset of marker data (see below). Column names are names of individuals. Row names are SNP IDs. The data set contains missing data (marked as NA).

```
     SNPID       AR124 AR124 AR144 AR144
[1,] "S10_28619" "G"   "A"   "A"   "A"
[2,] "S10_33499" "A"   "A"   "G"   "G"
[3,] "S10_47747" "T"   "T"   NA    NA
```

I want to determine imputation accuracy using 10-fold cross validation, so I need R to:

1. Mask 10% of the **known** SNPs a total of 10 different times (i.e. 10 rounds of masking).
2. Each round needs to mask a different set of SNPs.
3. **Each** SNP should only be masked once throughout these 10 rounds (e.g. SNP S10_28619 will show up as "NA" only once throughout the 10 rounds of masking).

This is the code I've been using:

```
##the function will return the marker matrix with an additional 10% missing data

CV10NA= function (input, seed, foldno) {#input is the SNP matrix, seed is the random number seed, fold number is a number indicating which cross validation fold you are on
set.seed(seed)
a = unlist(input)
b = is.na(a) #matrix b where TRUE indicates missing SNP and FALSE indicates known SNP 
pres = grep(FALSE, b) #finds cases of FALSE in matrix b and gives an integer vector containing the FALSEs' index numbers 
sets= sample(rep(1:10, c(length(pres)/10)), replace = FALSE) #repeat numbers 1 through 10 a total of length(pres)/10) times then randomly sample from values with no replacement 
a[which(sets==foldno)] = NA #find where sets==foldno in matrix a and replace it with NA
a = matrix(a, ncol = ncol(input))
return(a)
}
```

The function seems to work for foldno=1 through 9 but doesn't work when foldno=10. No error message appears. NOTE: I eliminated the column and row names before executing the function to prevent the function from treating them as "maskable" items.

Here's the output for foldno=1, 2, 3, and 10, respectively:

```
> CV10NA(beagle.subset, 1, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "G"  "A"  "A"  NA  
[2,] "A"  "A"  "G"  "G"
[3,] "T"  "T"  NA   NA  

> CV10NA(beagle.subset, 1, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "G"  "A"  "A"  "A"
[2,] "A"  NA   "G"  "G"
[3,] "T"  "T"  NA   NA

> CV10NA(beagle.subset, 1, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] NA   "A"  "A"  "A"
[2,] "A"  "A"  "G"  "G"
[3,] "T"  "T"  NA   NA

> CV10NA(beagle.subset, 1, 10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "G"  "A"  "A"  "A"
[2,] "A"  "A"  "G"  "G"
[3,] "T"  "T"  NA   NA
```

foldno=10 does not mask any SNP in the data set.

Any suggestions/feedback would be appreciated! 
I have no experience in programming, so please pardon me if I'm making an obvious error or ask a "stupid" question.

Additional attempts/thoughts: 
I tried debugging the code by running it line by line but nothing came out of it. I ran the code with another random seed number, and the problem doesn't seem to involve what value I assign to foldno. The SNP in [2,4] of the matrix just doesn't mask, regardless of foldno and seed number.

---

For anyone interested, here's the revised code I used for masking:

```
CV10NA= function (input, seed, foldno) { 
set.seed(seed)
a = unlist(input)
b = is.na(a) 
pres = grep(FALSE, b)
pres = sample(pres)
sets= sample(rep(1:10, length(pres)/10), replace = FALSE)
a[pres[which(sets==foldno)]] = NA
a = matrix(a, ncol = ncol(input))
enter code here
return(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So `sets` is a permutation of the numbers 1-10, e.g.:

```
3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
```

And you want to find out the index of the value that is equal to the fold number:

```
which(sets==foldno)
```

The problem is, this will only return numbers in the range of 1-10. Thus, here are the values in `beagle.subset` that can potentially be set to NA:

```
> beagle.subset[1:10]
 [1] "G" "A" "T" "A" "A" "T" "A" "G" NA  "A"
```

Notice how one of them is already `NA`! There's no way that `beagle.subset[2,4]` will ever be affected, since it's at index 11. Instead, `beagle.subset[3,3]` will just be set to `NA`--again.

I think that instead of shuffling 1-10, you want to shuffle the indices that are non-`NA`. Then you can assign each of these a value of 1-10, essentially placing them into ten bins.

```
pres = sample(pres)
bins = seq_along(pres) %% 10 + 1 
a[pres[bins == foldno]] = NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Peyton! I tried your code, and it works for beagle.subset. Unfortunately, I tried the code on a larger data set, and it doesn't generate the results I want.

I want to mask 10% of the known SNPs with each round of masking (for a total of 10 rounds). At the end of all 10 runs, all the known SNPs should have been masked exactly 1 time. Therefore, each round needs to mask a different set of SNPs (and one set will ever mask the same SNP as another set). 

This is what I was hoping to achieve (but failed) with: 
sets= sample(rep(1:10, length(pres)/10), replace = FALSE)

Comment: (Sorry, ran out of characters.)
The code you provided masks only 1 SNP at a time (instead of 10%). Sorry, I should have provided a larger data set in my question to avoid confusion. Do you have any more recommendations? Thank you again for your help @Peyton!

Comment: Good catch! I fixed this. Now the code assigns each index in pres a value from 1-10.

Comment: Dude, thanks a bunch @Peyton! Your code works perfectly! And it helped me figure out what I was doing wrong in my initial code. Instead of " a[which(sets==foldno)] = NA ", I should have written " a[pres[which(sets==foldno)]] = NA "!